# Check whether scroll is finished using AppleScript

Tags: scroll, applescript

I have an **AppleScript** script to open the Mail app, open a mail, scroll down and take screenshot of the whole mail body. I am taking the screenshot by scrolling the page using **keystroke 121 (page down)**. I don't know how much time I have to repeat the loop to reach the page end. Is there anyway we can identify if the scroll has reached the page end using AppleScript?

This is my code snippet for page down and taking screenshot:

```
open each_message
tell application "System Events"
    delay 5
    keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
    delay 3
    key code 20 using {command down, shift down}
    delay 5
    key code 121
    delay 5
    key code 20 using {command down, shift down}
    delay 5
    keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
end tell
```

Comment: Don't know about the scrolling thing but have you considered trying to print each message to a pdf instead? If you really need images, then you could convert the pdfs.

Comment: @Mockman I tried that, but in that case html rendering is taking place. I need to take the screenshot of exactly how the mail is appearing in the apple mail.

Comment: That's tough. Is there a practical limit to the size of each message? If so, you could probably resize the window bounds (i.e. make them tall enough so that the entire message fits in the window) and then just capture one (or two) window grabs. Or is keeping the existing window size also a requirement? FWIW, your delay times seem high and could likely be reduced. Finally, I don't think a built-in mechanism exists but… depending on how the scroll bars are set, you could perhaps check for pixel coloration at the bottom of the scroll bar after each page down.

Comment: That is the real issue. The height of the messages may vary. And currently I am maximising the window and taking the screenshot 3 times. For some emails, it's fine. For some, it is duplicating the last page, for some, the screenshots are incomplete.

Comment: Depending upon your display, you may be able to scale the resolution to something higher, for example, on my MBP, I can increase by 1/3 (900 to 1200). Or, if you have an external display that pivots, you could then get a significant boost in vertical pixels (to 1920 for mine).

Comment: @Mockman I have an alternative way to scroll up from the end. Is there anyway in applescript to know whether we reached the top? Can we check visibility of an element using applescript?

Comment: You might be able to do something with UI scripting the 'scroll bar'. I don't really use Mail but in Safari this would likely work. Once you root around and find the relevant scroll bar, get its properties (especially 'position'). Then scroll down and get them again. You should find that when the window is at its top, the right-hand number (y-axis) is positive, and as you scroll down, it becomes negative. So it is possible that you can get after every page up action and when the scroll bar position is positive, then you're done. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Here is the code example for Safari. It should be inside a safari tell block that includes 'activate'. At the end are the initial result and again after page down —  `tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to position of scroll bar 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1` --{1375, 98} --{1375, -702}. You should be able to find the same for Mail.

Comment: Yeah, let me try that for Apple mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question and ensuing comments...

> Is there anyway we can identify if the scroll has reached the page end using AppleScript?

**Yes**

> For some emails, it's fine. For some, it is duplicating the last page, for some, the screenshots are incomplete.   <sub>(From comments under the question.)</sub>

That is the nature of different length documents and pressing the **Page Down** *key*, and why maybe using a *third-party application* like [Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) is a better way to go.

That all said...

---

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

As you did not include the complete *code* of your *script*, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is presented more as a *proof of concept*. It too may/will have extra screenshots, however, it ensures the page it all the way to the top before it starts taking the screenshots and ensures a screenshot of the whole last page is taken too, based on it stopping appropriately.

For testing purposes I started with an individual email opened in its own *window*, assuming that is what the `open each_message` at the top of the *code* you included does or represents.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Mail" to activate

delay 1

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
    delay 1
    repeat while my getEmailFullScreenWindowScrollPosition() > 0.0
        key code 116
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    delay 1
    repeat while my getEmailFullScreenWindowScrollPosition() < 1.0
        key code 20 using {command down, shift down}
        delay 1
        key code 121
        delay 1
    end repeat
    key code 121
    delay 1
    key code 20 using {command down, shift down}
    delay 1
    keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
end tell

to getEmailFullScreenWindowScrollPosition()
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        return value of ¬
            scroll bar 1 of ¬
            scroll area 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "Mail"
end getEmailFullScreenWindowScrollPosition
```

**Notes:**

In **Mail** in **macOS Catalina** on my system there was no *horizontal scroll bar* when an opened email in its own *window* is in **Full Screen** *view*, and why the *handler* is directed to `scroll bar 1`. However, if you do need to query for its `orientation`, then for the *handler* use:

```applescript
to getEmailFullScreenWindowScrollPosition()
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        return value of ¬
            first scroll bar of ¬
            scroll area 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "Mail" whose ¬
            orientation is ¬
            "AXVerticalOrientation"
end getEmailFullScreenWindowScrollPosition
```

In testing the **getEmailFullScreenWindowScrollPosition()** *handler*, it would report `1.0` when there was still some page left but not showing on the screen, so I added the additional lines of *code* after the second `repeat` *loop* to ensure it was all captured.

The test email had content to the very end of the page and maybe isn't really representative of most emails. If you find that there is ample white space at the end of your emails then you may want to remove the following lines of *code* after the second `repeat` *loop*:

```applescript
key code 121
delay 1
key code 20 using {command down, shift down}
```

Also note that I ended up using `delay 1` for all but one of the `delay` *commands*, and it worked fine for me in testing, however, adjust as necessary for your system.

As this is just being presented as a *proof of concept*, I'll leave it to you to tweak the *code* to fit your needs.

<sub>Note that I am not affiliated with the developer of **Snagit** and have mentioned it as a possible option to capturing the entire scroll area of the screen in a single screenshot.</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Wow! @user3439894 You made my day! This was exactly the one I was looking for. Some tweaks are needed from my end for the purpose, but I am sure this one helps me the most.

Comment: Hey, I missed that in the excitement. Marked your answer as the accepted. i don't have enough reputation to upvote. Sure, I shall do that later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handler that returns the current vertical scroll bar position for a message viewed in the frontmost message viewer. It makes a bunch of assumptions about which panels you have open and what orientation the viewer has, but it should give you something to work with:

```
set sp to my findMailScrollPosition()

on findMailScrollPosition()
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Mail"
            tell window 1
                tell splitter group 1
                    tell splitter group 1
                        tell scroll area 2
                            tell (first scroll bar whose orientation is "AXVerticalOrientation")
                                -- this will return a value between 0 and 1 (top to bottom)
                                return value
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end findMailScrollPosition
```